# Capistrano asset precompile error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, capistrano, sprockets

When I use capistrano to push to my production server I get this error:

```
executing "cd /var/www/my_app/releases/20120731082050 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile"
servers: ["my_app.com"]
[my_app.com] executing command
*** [err :: my_app.com] /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 /var/www/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake assets:precompile:nondigest RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
*** [err :: my_app.com] 
command finished in 74149ms
```

The precompile works despite the error. I've tried running

```
cd /var/www/my_app/releases/20120731082050 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile
```

On the server and it works but it prints this to the console:

```
/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 /var/www/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake assets:precompile:nondigest RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
```

which matches the capistrano output (Notice the addition of 'nondigest' from the original call. I know it's not a fatal error because it still works but how would I stop it from printing this error?

Comment: try putting --trace on the end to get a full stack trace, i.e: cd /var/www/my_app/releases/20120731082050 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile --trace

Answer (score 0):

I just overrided `deploy:assets` task with my own code:

```rb
namespace :deploy
  task :assets do
    run "cd #{current_path} && bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run `rake assets:precompile`, how to avoid default output

the solution is to **add `-q` behand your command**,

e.g. `executing "cd /var/www/my_app/releases/20120731082050 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile -q"`

analysis is below, if you want to see:

```
# :gem_path/actionpack/lib/sprockets/assets.rake
namespace :assets do

  # task entry, it will call invoke_or_reboot_rake_task
  task :precompile do
    invoke_or_reboot_rake_task "assets:precompile:all"
  end

  # it will call ruby_rake_task
  def invoke_or_reboot_rake_task(task)
    ruby_rake_task task
  end

  # it will call ruby
  def ruby_rake_task(task, fork = true)
    env    = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'production'
    groups = ENV['RAILS_GROUPS'] || 'assets'
    args   = [$0, task,"RAILS_ENV=#{env}","RAILS_GROUPS=#{groups}"]
    ruby(*args)
  end
end

# :gem_path/rake/file_utils.rb
module FileUtils

  # it will call sh
  def ruby(*args,&block)
    options = (Hash === args.last) ? args.pop : {}
    sh(*([RUBY] + args + [options]), &block)
  end

  # it will call set_verbose_option
  # and if options[:verbose] == true, it do not output cmd
  #   but default of options[:verbose] is an object
  def sh(*cmd, &block)
    # ...
    set_verbose_option(options)
    # ...
    Rake.rake_output_message cmd.join(" ") if options[:verbose]
    # ...
  end

  # default of options[:verbose] is Rake::FileUtilsExt::DEFAULT, which is an object
  def set_verbose_option(options) # :nodoc:
    unless options.key? :verbose
      options[:verbose] =
        Rake::FileUtilsExt.verbose_flag == Rake::FileUtilsExt::DEFAULT ||
        Rake::FileUtilsExt.verbose_flag
    end
  end
end

# :gem_path/rake/file_utils_ext.rb
module Rake
  module FileUtilsExt
    DEFAULT = Object.new
  end
end

# :gem_path/rake/application.rb
          # the only to solve the disgusting output when run `rake assets:precompile`
          #   is add a `-q` option.
          ['--quiet', '-q',
            "Do not log messages to standard output.",
            lambda { |value| Rake.verbose(false) }
          ],
          ['--verbose', '-v',
            "Log message to standard output.",
            lambda { |value| Rake.verbose(true) }
          ],
```